# Atributos de clase

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, clase

Quiero saber si es posible llamar a una función mediante un atributo de una clase, por ejemplo, si hago `className.sort_asc` quiero ejecute una función para ordenar los datos de forma ascendiente.

```py
class Numeros():
     __init__(self,nums):
          self.nums = [nums]
```

Sé que los atributos pueden ser de Clase o de instancia, en este caso es de instancia, por lo que el atributo debería de estar dentro del *constructor*, `__init__`

```
class Numeros():
     def __init__(self,nums):
          self.nums = [nums]
          self.sort = sorted(self.nums)
      
     def add_number(self,n):
           self.nums += [n]
```

Sin embargo no muestra el resultado esperado

```
num = Numeros(3)
print(num.nums)
# [3]

num.add_number(5)
print(num.nums)
# [3, 5]

print(num.sort)
# [3]   <---- ¿Por que?
```

¿Por qué pasa esto? además, ¿Se puede ejecutar una función con un atributo de clase?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creo que tienes un poco lío entre los siguientes términos:

- Atributo de clase
- Atributo de instancia
- Método de clase
- Método de instancia

### Diferencia entre Método y atributo

- Un atributo es una variable que pertenece a una clase/instancia
- Un método es una función que pertenece a una clase/instancia

### Diferencia entre un atributo de clase y un atributo de instancia

Los **atributos de instancia** pertenecen a dicha instancia, es decir, podemos crear otras instancias provenientes de la misma clase, con distintos atributos.

Por otro lado los **atributos de clase** pertenecen a dicha clase y por tanto siempre que dicha clase sea creada, se inicializará con el mismo atributo de clase. Que se puede cambiar en todas las instancias, simplemente llamando a la clase. Siguiendo con tu ejemplo

```
class Numeros():

    tipo = "Enteros"

    def __init__(self,nums):
        self.nums = [nums]
        self.sort = sorted(self.nums)
      
    def add_number(self,n):
        self.nums += [n] 

#Creamos dos instancias
nm = Numeros([1,4,3,2,7])
nm2 = Numeros([0,5,4,2,10])

print(nm.tipo, nm2.tipo)
```

**Salida:** `Enteros Enteros`

Como dije, podemos cambiar nuestro atributo de clase en todas las instancias, simplemente haciéndolo en la clase:

```
Numeros.tipo = "Racionales

print(nm.tipo, nm2.tipo)
```

**Salida:** `Racionales, Racionales`

Por supuesto también lo podemos hacer en cada instancia si es necesario, pero esto le quita el sentido de  **atributo de clase**

### Diferencia entre método de clase y método de instancia

Al igual que con los atributos, la diferencia entre los métodos de clase y los métodos de instancia es que los métodos de clase, pertenecen a la clase, y los métodos de instancias pertenecen a las distintas instancias derivadas de una clase. Para esta explicación voy a crear una clase nueva que lo hará más sencillo

```
class Saludo:

    def hola():
        print("hola!")

    def inst_hola(self):
        print(f"Hola me has llamado desde {self}")

    @classmethod
    def cls_hello(cls):
        print(f"hola me has llamado desde {cls}")
```

Tenemos la clase `Hola`, vamos a ver el primer método que es un método de clase. Si llamamos a la función `hola()` tenemos que hacerlo desde la clase.

```
print(Saludo.hola())
```

**Salida:** "hola!"

¿Qué pasa si instanciamos la clase y llamamos al método `hola()`?

```
saludo = Saludo()
print(saludo.hola())
```

**Salida:** `TypeError: hola() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Nos da un error, porque nosotros hemos dicho que el método `hola()` **pertenece a la clase, no a las instancias**. Python internamente, **cuando llamas a un método desde una instancia, siempre le inserta un parámetro que es la propia instancia**. Por eso cuando defines los métodos de instancia se utiliza `self`. Como nuestro método de clase `hola()` no tiene ningún argumento en su definición, Python internamente le pasa como argumento la propia instancia y obviamente da el error `TypeError: hola() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` porque nuestro método `hola()` no toma ningún argumento.

Este error pasa exactamente al contrario si ejecutamos un método de instancia en una clase, nos dará un error diciendo que nos falta el argumento `self` es decir que hemos definido el método con un argumento y no le estamos pasando ninguno, puedes hacer la prueba tu mismo.

Por último tenemos el decorador `@classmethod` que hace que los métodos de clases puedan ser llamados desde una instancia y desde la clase, sin que ocurran los problemas anteriores.

Si ejecutamos lo siguiente puedes ver desde dónde están siendo llamadas las funciones

```
saludo.inst_hola() #llamamos a la instancia
saludo.cls_hola() #llamamos a la clase, a pesar de que es una instancia
Saludo.cls_hola() #llamamos a la clase
```

**Salida:**

```
Hola me has llamado desde <__main__.Saludo object at 0x7fc6c0132d30>
hola me has llamado desde <class '__main__.Saludo'>
hola me has llamado desde <class '__main__.Saludo'>
```

## La solución a tu problema.

Una vez explicado todo esto, vamos con tu problema. Este se puede resolver de la siguiente forma:

```
class Numeros():

    tipo = "Enteros"

    def __init__(self, nums):
        self.sort = sorted(nums)
      
    def add_number(self,n):
        self.sort += [n]
        self.sort = sorted(self.sort)


nm = Numeros([1,4,3,2,7])
nm.add_number(5)
print(nm.sort)
```

**Salida:** `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]`

Genial, **simplemente los ordenas cada vez que llamas al método**. Aunque creo que a lo que te refieres es a lo se conoce como **Propiedades de instancia**

### Propiedades de instancia

Las propiedades de instancia, es una forma de programar nuestros atributos para que cada vez que sean consultados, **se haga con un proceso determinado** que es lo que estás buscando (por eso me ha parecido conveniente aclarar los anteriores términos hasta llegar aquí). Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
class Numeros():

    tipo = "Enteros"

    def __init__(self, nums):
        self._sort = nums #creamos _sort
      
    @property
    def sort(self):
        return sorted(self._sort) #llamamos a _sort de una manera determinada, usando sort

    def add_number(self,n):
        self._sort += [n] #almacenamos el número en _sort


nm = Numeros([1,4,3,2,7])
nm.add_number(5)
print(nm.sort)
```

**Salida:** `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]`

En este caso, cuando llamas a `sort` realmente estás llamando a una **propiedad de instancia** que consulta nuestro atributo `self._sort` de una forma determinada, es decir, ordenándolo. Este procedimiento se "asimila" (no es lo mismo) a la forma de crear atributos como en Java o C++ en los que no es recomendable acceder a los atributos directamente (como se hace en Python).

### Bono Extra

- `self` es una forma genérica por convención que existe en Python de referirse a la instancia de una clase, **no es una sintaxis reservada del lenguaje** pero podría ser cualquier otra cosa, por ejemplo "pepito", aunque no es recomendable, ya que haría tu código difícil de entender.
- Hay personas que utilizan las **propiedades de instancia** pensando que están creando atributos privados como en Java o C++, esto no es así, en Python no existen los atributos privados, y siempre es accesible
- En el ejemplo hemos creado en el constructor el atributo `self._sort`. La barra baja es una convención en Python (realmente es más que una convención, pero vamos a dejarlo aquí) que le indica a otros programadores "Este atributo no debes de acceder a el utilizando `_sort` debes acceder utilizando su propiedad de instancia"