# Buscar el nombre del objeto en un txt

Tags: python, poo

Tengo una duda respecto a un proyecto que estoy haciendo, el proyecto consta de covid-19 por lo que me gustaría que alguien bondadoso me ayude con esto. Ahora me estoy enfocando en la función 9 `contagiosTotales()` Lo que tengo que hacer es ingresar a un **txt** que pondré mas abajo con la intención de en base al nombre de una provincia dado, conseguir la cantidad de contagios totales que esta posee.

```
class Pais:
    nombre = ''
    contagiosTotales = 0
    contagiosDiarios = 0
    contagiosActivos = 0
    muertesTotales = 0
    muertesDiarias = 0
    vacunasAplicadas = 0
    vacunasSinAplicar = 0
    vacunasTotales = 0

    def __init__(self,nombre,contagiosTotales, contagiosDiarios, contagiosActivos, muertesTotales, muertesDiarias, vacunasAplicadas, vacunasSinAplicar, vacunasTotales):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.contagiosTotales = contagiosTotales
        self.contagiosDiarios = contagiosDiarios
        self.contagiosActivos = contagiosActivos
        self.muertesTotales = muertesTotales
        self.muertesDiarias = muertesDiarias
        self.vacunasAplicadas = vacunasAplicadas
        self.vacunasSinAplicar = vacunasSinAplicar
        self.vacunasTotales = vacunasTotales

class Provincia(Pais):
    nombre = ''
    contagiosTotales = 0
    contagiosDiarios = 0
    contagiosActivos = 0
    muertesTotales = 0
    muertesDiarias = 0
    vacunasAplicadas = 0
    vacunasSinAplicar = 0
    vacunasTotales = 0

    def __init__(self,nombre,contagiosTotales, contagiosDiarios, contagiosActivos, muertesTotales, muertesDiarias, vacunasAplicadas, vacunasSinAplicar, vacunasTotales):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.contagiosTotales = contagiosTotales
        self.contagiosDiarios = contagiosDiarios
        self.contagiosActivos = contagiosActivos
        self.muertesTotales = muertesTotales
        self.muertesDiarias = muertesDiarias
        self.vacunasAplicadas = vacunasAplicadas
        self.vacunasSinAplicar = vacunasSinAplicar
        self.vacunasTotales = vacunasTotales
    def contagiosTotales():
        f = open('covid.txt', 'r')
        f.read()
        provincia = input("Ingrese el nombre de la provincia que desea:")
        for e in f:
            if provincia == e.find(provincia):
                print("Es verdadero")
            else:
                print("No existe")
        f.close()

    def agregarProvincia(self):
        self.provincia = input("Ingrese el nombre de la provincia nueva:")
        self.contagiosDiarios = input("Ingrese el numero de contagios diarios:")
        self.contagiosTotales = input("Ingrese el numero de contagios totales:")
        self.contagiosActivos = input("Ingrese el numero de contagios activos:")
        self.muertesTotales = input("Ingrese el numero de muertes totales:")
        self.muertesDiarias = input("Ingrese el numero de muertes diarias:")
        self.vacunasAplicadas = input("Ingrese el numero de vacunas aplicadas:")
        self.vacunasSinAplicar = input("Ingrese el numero de vacunas sin aplicar:")
        self.vacunasTotales = input("Ingrese el numero de vacunas totales:")
        f = open('covid.txt', 'r')
        for e in f.readlines():
            posicion = e[1]
        numero = int(max(posicion)) + 1
        f = open ('covid.txt','a')
        f.write('\n' + 'p' + str(numero) + ':')
        f.write(self.provincia + '|')
        f.write(self.contagiosTotales + '|')
        f.write(self.contagiosDiarios + '|')
        f.write(self.contagiosActivos + '|')
        f.write(self.muertesTotales + '|')
        f.write(self.muertesDiarias + '|')
        f.write(self.vacunasAplicadas + '|')
        f.write(self.vacunasSinAplicar + '|')
        f.write(self.vacunasTotales)
        f.close()
    def imprimir(self):
        print("Nombre de la provincia:" + self.nombre + "Contagios totales:" + self.contagiosTotales + "Contagios Diarios:" + self.contagiosDiarios + "Contagios activos:" + self.contagiosActivos + "Muertes totales:" + self.muertesTotales + "Muertes diarias:" + self.muertesDiarias + "Vacunas aplicadas:" + self.vacunasAplicadas + "Vacunas sin aplicar:" + self.vacunasSinAplicar + "Vacunas totales:" + self.vacunasTotales)


def inicio():
    while True:
        print("1)Pais con mas contagios totales")
        print("2)Pais con mas contagios diarios")
        print("3)Pais con mas contagios activos")
        print("4)Pais con mas muertes totales")
        print("5)Pais con mas muertes diarias")
        print("6)Pais con mas vacunas aplicadas")
        print("7)Pais con mas vacunas sin aplicar")
        print("8)Pais que posee mas vacunas")
        print("9)Provincia con mas contagios totales")
        print("10)Provincia con mas contagios diarios")
        print("11)Provincia con mas contagios activos")
        print("12)Provincia con mas muertes totales")
        print("13)Provincia con mas muertes diarias")
        print("14)Provincia con mas vacunas aplicadas")
        print("15)Provincia con mas vacunas sin aplicar")
        print("16)Provincia que posee mas vacunas")
        print("17)Agregar muertos")
        print("18)Agregar un nuevo lote de vacunas")
        print("19)Agregar una nueva provincia")
        print("20)Agregar un pais nuevo")
        print("21)Ver todos los paises en el mundo")
        print("22)Ver las provincias de un pais")
        print("23)Ver las provincias de todos los paises ordenadas de forma alfabetica")
        print("24)Inversiones")
        print("0) Salir")
        numeroIngresado = int(input("Ingrese el numero que desea:"))
        if numeroIngresado == 19:
            Provincia.agregarProvincia()
            break
        if numeroIngresado == 9:
            Provincia.contagiosTotales()
            break
        if numeroIngresado == 0:
            break
inicio()
```

El txt es esto:

```
p1:a|12|1234|12|12|12|12|12|12
p2:b|12|1234|12|12|12|12|12|12
```

Es decir, que si el usuario ingresa a o b el programa le devuelve 1234. Ahora bien, use estos números de ejemplo pero necesito que el programa sea dinámico. Gracias a todos los que me ayuden.

Comment: Esto no parece una pregunta, más bien es como una orden de trabajo.

Comment: Y como hago para poner un texto con formato? Es la primera vez que hago una pregunta aca

Comment: No!! Jajaja no es una orden de trabajo sino una consulta, si podes ayudarme me viene genial

Comment: Bueno gracias, lo voy a tener en cuenta para la proxima

Comment: Bueno me gustaria eliminar esta publicacion para poder formularla bien, como hago?

Comment: Listo creo que ya pude lograr que se entienda el planteo

Comment: Creo que no se entiende exactamente lo que te hace falta, te hace falta la lectura o escritura? que problemas presenta el código que actualmente tienes?

Comment: Nose como hacer la funcion para que lea el txt y asi dado el nombre de una provincia, saber la cantidad de casos totales que tiene. Es un problema de escritura

Answer (score 0):

Luego de experimentar con las expresiones regulares (no me llevo muy bien con ellas >_<) y por lo que entiendo de la pregunta es que quieres obtener los casos totales según la provincia que se ingrese. para ello se usa una expresión regular que busque los números según la provincia, dado que la provincia esta en un archivo, lo que hice fue simular la función `readlines()` el cual lee el archivo con un ciclo `for`. Aparte tu código esta mal optimizado, creo que el tema de POO es nuevo para ti.

**Mejoras**

Se simplifica la creación de variables, en python no hay la necesidad de declarar una variable antes de asignarle un valor, además el constructor de una clase *`__init__()`* creara las variables una vez la clase sea llamada, por lo que podemos hacer esto:

```py
class Pais:
    def __init__(self,nombre,contagiosTotales, contagiosDiarios, contagiosActivos, muertesTotales, muertesDiarias, vacunasAplicadas, vacunasSinAplicar, vacunasTotales):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.contagiosTotales = contagiosTotales
        self.contagiosDiarios = contagiosDiarios
        self.contagiosActivos = contagiosActivos
        self.muertesTotales = muertesTotales
        self.muertesDiarias = muertesDiarias
        self.vacunasAplicadas = vacunasAplicadas
        self.vacunasSinAplicar = vacunasSinAplicar
        self.vacunasTotales = vacunasTotales
```

Al hacer esto se simplifica código, pero ya no podrás llamar a las variables sin una instancia, no podrás hacer `Pais.nombre`, deberás hacer la instancia `Pais().nombre`, es esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/451861/183782) encontraras mas información.

En tu funcion `inicio()` llamas a otra clase `Provincia()` la cual hereda de `Pais()`, si esta heredando de `Pais()` esto quiere decir que la clase hija tambien tendrá sus métodos y atributos, por lo que no hace falta crear otra vez las variables, en vez de eso se usa `super().__init__()` el cual ejecuta el metodo init de la clase padre.

```py
#importamos el modulo de expresiones regulares
import re

class Provincia(Pais):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def contagiosTotales():
        provincias = [] #aqui se almacenaran las provincias
        #f = open('covid.txt', 'r')
        #f.read()
        #for e in f:
            #provincias.append(e) #cada linea se agregara a la lista
            #print("Agregado")
        #f.close()

        #la lista deberá quedar asi
        provincias = ["p1:a|12|1234|12|12|12|12|12|12","p2:b|12|1234|12|12|12|12|12|12"]
        
        #preguntamos
        provincia = input("Ingrese el nombre de la provincia que desea:")

        #creamos la expresión regular para obtener los números
        regex = re.compile(r'\|(\w+\d+)+?')

        #recorremos la lista y aplicamos nuestra expresión regular
        for prov in provincias:
          if provincia in prov: 
            casos = re.findall(regex, prov)
            #casos devuelve una liista con los numero pero en string
            #hay que convertirlos a entero para poder sumar
            casos = sum([ int(caso) for caso in casos])
            #esto nos dara el total de casos 
            print(casos)
   ...
```

Esto aun se puede optimizar, te puedes ahorrar un ciclo `for`, pero eso te lo dejo a ti :).