# Acceder a atributos desde otra clase

Tags: python, spyder

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio de clases y objetos pero me surge un problema a la hora de llamar a un atributo de la clase anterior.
Tengo una clase que se llama `Line` que viene definida por dos parámetros, una lista de estaciones y otra con los tiempos entre estaciones.

```
class Line:

   def __init__(self, nombres_estaciones, tiempo_tray):
       self.nombres_estaciones = nombres_estaciones
       self.tiempo_tray = tiempo_tray
  
   def __str__(self):
       texto = str(self.nombres_estaciones[0])
       for e in range(1, len(self.nombres_estaciones)):
           texto = texto + " --> " + str(self.nombres_estaciones[e]) 
       return texto
```

y así compruebo que funciona la clase `Line`

```
line1 = Line(['Embajadores', 'Lavapiés', 'Sol', 'Callao'], [40, 103, 81])
print(line1)
line2 = Line(['Atocha', 'Sol', 'Valdecarros'], [22, 42])
print(line2)
```

Y después tengo la clase metro:

```
class Metro:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.dic_lines = {}
            
    def add_line(self, line_name, line):
        if line_name in self.dic_lines:
            raise MetroException("La linea - " + line_name + " - ya esta introducida")
        else:
            self.dic_lines[line_name] = (line.nombres_estaciones, line.tiempo_tray)
        return self.dic_lines
    
    def cabecera_de_linea(self, line_name):
        if line_name in self.dic_lines:
            cabezera = line.nombres_estaciones[0]
        return cabecera
    
    def __str__(self):
        texto = ''
        for clave in self.dic_lines:
            texto += str(clave) + ' '
        return texto
```

Añado una linea al diccionario:

```
m = Metro()
m.add_line('Linea 3', line1)
>>> {'Linea 3': (['Embajadores', 'Lavapiés', 'Sol', 'Callao'], [40, 103, 81])}
```

Y el problema está aquí, al probar la función de cabecera de linea

```
m.cabecera_de_linea('Linea 3')
```

me dice que `line is not define` y no sé como definir `line`. Tampoco puedo llamar a otras funciones desde otras clases porque me ocurre lo mismo.

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, o que me explique como puedo acceder al objeto de la clase `Line` desde la clase `Metro`.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno es un problema simple, pero con una explicación un poco compleja, podrías usar herencia para evitar hacer algunas cosas, pero no creí necesario reestructurar la mayoría del código cuando solo se necesita cambiar 2 líneas

```py
class Line:
   def __init__(self, nombres_estaciones, tiempo_tray):
       self.nombres_estaciones = nombres_estaciones
       self.tiempo_tray = tiempo_tray
   #reemplazamos el metodo __str__ por __repr__
   def __repr__(self):
       #nos ahorramos un ciclo, gracias a la funcion .join()
       texto =  " --> ".join(self.nombres_estaciones) 
       return texto
```

Creí conveniente utilizar el *dunder method* `__repr__` ya que nos permite imprimir el valor tanto desde la creación del objeto (`print(Line(...))`) como desde su instancia (`print(line1)`)
Tu problema no esta en hacer referencia a un atributo de la clase, lo podemos ver haciendo esto

```py
line1 = Line(['Embajadores', 'Lavapiés', 'Sol', 'Callao'], [40, 103, 81])
#print(line1)

#accedeos a uno de sus atributos
print(line1.nombres_estaciones)
#salida -> ['Embajadores', 'Lavapiés', 'Sol', 'Callao']
```

Esto quiere decir que si se puede acceder a sus atributos de instancia, y puede ser usado donde sea.

**Error**
Ahora pasando a tu error en la función `cabecera_de_linea` el cual es solo un error de lógica, pues en la función nunca pasa el valor de `line` por lo que te da un error, lo que quieres es acceder al valor de `line_name` que será la lista de estaciones, la que "casualmente" esta guardada en el diccionario

**Solución**
Como dije los datos de cada *"linea"* los almacenas en un diccionario, la cual tiene como clave el nombre de la *"linea"* y como valor sus *"estaciones"*, solo accedemos a la *key* para obtener su valor. además hay un error de tipeo, estas cambiando el nombre de las variables asignas `cabezera` y retornas `cabecera`, aquí se utilizara la variable `cabecera`.

```py
    ...
    def cabecera_de_linea(self, line_name):
        if line_name in self.dic_lines:
            #si accedemos a la key de un diccionario nos retorna su valor
            #asi que hacemos eso
            cabecera = self.dic_lines[line_name]
            #si ponemos este return fuera, dara un error en caso no se cumpla la condicion
            return cabecera
        return #es igual que return None
```

**Probamos**

```py
#instanciamos la clase
m = Metro()
m.add_line('Linea 1', line1)
#salida -> {'Linea 1': (['Embajadores', 'Lavapiés', 'Sol', 'Callao'], [40, 103, 81])}

cabecera = m.cabecera_de_linea('Linea 1') 
print(cabecera)
#salida -> (['Embajadores', 'Lavapiés', 'Sol', 'Callao'], [40, 103, 81])
```

Si quieres saber mas sobre los atributos de clase y de instancia puedes leer esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/451915/183782)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha quedado todo mucho más claro con la respuesta tuya y la que me has dejado como link.

Comment: De nada, estoy aqui para ayudar :)

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar deberías revisar la sintaxis, la variable la definis como "cabezera" y la devolves como "cabecera". En español se escribe cabecera, pero lo importante es que se llamen igual en ambos lados.

Respecto al código, la forma correcta sería:

```
def cabecera_de_linea(self, line_name):
        if line_name in self.dic_lines:
            //Obtiene la linea y luego el primer dato de la tupla
            cabecera = self.dic_lines[line_name][0]
        return cabecera
```

Mi recomendación, de todas maneras es que en add_line directamente asignes como valor el objeto line. Así, si hubiese cambios en la línea, se reflejaría automáticamente en el metro. Hecho de esa manera quedaría:

```
def add_line(self, line_name, line):
    if line_name in self.dic_lines:
        raise MetroException("La linea - " + line_name + " - ya esta introducida")
    else:
        self.dic_lines[line_name] = line
    return self.dic_lines

def cabecera_de_linea(self, line_name):
    if line_name in self.dic_lines:
        cabecera = self.dic_lines[line_name].nombres_estaciones[0]
    return cabecera
```

Comment: Muchas graciaas!! Ya puedo acceder a funciones y a atributos de otras clases.