# Objetos y herencias Python

Tags: python, poo, herencia

llevo unos días haciendo un programa para aprender Python. He realizado lo básico con variables y ahora quisiera meterle objetos pero pasa lo siguiente:

Cuando declaro la clase padre ***FigurasGeometricas*** y sus hijos ***Triangulo*** y ***Rectangulo*** en un archivo aparte, no puedo hacer referencia a los hijos, solo al padre. No entiendo porqué. Vengo de Java y es posible que esté intentando hacerlo de la manera errónea pero, siempre que miro documentación al respecto, tanto la oficial como web y blogs, lo realizan todo en el mismo archivo y no me parece ordenado meter todo en el mismo archivo, aunque sean partes bien diferenciadas.

Clase main:

```
import funcionesCalculadora
import FigurasGeometricas

figura = 0

opcion=1
while opcion>0 and opcion<6 :
    nLados=int(input("Antes de empezar necesito que me digas cuántos lados tiene la figura geométrica: "))
    if nLados==3:
        base=float(input("Introduce la base: "))
        altura=float(input("Introduce ahora la altura: "))
        #Colocar en el futuro una opción de si está correcto los datos.
        figura = Triangulo(nLados,base,altura)
        
    elif nLados==4:
        #figura = FigurasGeometricas.Rectangulos(nLados,0,0)
        break
```

Clase de los objetos:

```
import math

class FigurasGeometricas:

    def _init_(self, nLados):
        self.nLados=nLados

class Triangulo(FigurasGeometricas):

    def _init_(self,nLados,base,altura):
        FigurasGeometricas._init_(self, nLados)
        self.base=base
        self.altura=altura
        self.hipotenusa=self.calcularHipotenusa()

    def calcularArea(self):
        area=self.base*self.altura/2
        return area

    def calcularPerimetro(self):
        perimetro=self.altura+self.base+self.hipotenusa
        return perimetro

    def calcularHipotenusa(self):
        bCuadrado=math.pow(self.base,2)
        aCuadrado=math.pow(self.altura,2)
        hipotenusa=math.sqrt(bCuadrado+aCuadrado)
        return hipotenusa

class Rectangulo(FigurasGeometricas):

    def _init_(self, base, altura):
        self.base=base
        self.altura=altura
```

Comment: podrías poner el código respecto a tu clase y el modo de así, así entenderemos mejor y podremos ayudarte

Comment: Puedes leer esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/453454/183782)

Comment: He editado el texto con el código, Christian. Me pongo a mirar la respuesta que me has facilitado, a ver si me ayuda. Gracias!

Comment: he formateado el código, pero no esta bien identado, por favor indentalo bien. Cpia y pega el codigo dentro de 3 backtick ```` asi```

Comment: Ya lo he corregido, en principio. Estoy muy verde con esto, ya lo lamento. Te tendría que dar error en la línea  "figura = Triangulo(nLados,base,altura)" ya que no encuentra la clase de Triangulo. Por cierto, he mirado la respuesta que me has facilitado pero no me sirve, ya que el tiene problemas para llamar una clase pero yo tengo problemas con llamar a una clase hijo"

Comment: tienes que hacer `FigurasGeometricas.Triangulo(nLados,base,altura)`

Comment: Esa ha sido mi primer intento pero no funciona. No encuentra la clase Triangulo. Me pone esto: figura = FigurasGeometricas.Triangulo(nLados,base,altura)
TypeError: Triangulo() takes no arguments

Comment: como se llama tu archivo donde tiene las clases de los objetos?

Comment: tienes que importar tu archivo y luego importas las clases

Comment: Pues se llama igual, se llama FigurasGeometricas... ¿Puede ser ese el problema, que lo confunda con una librería en ves de una clase?

Comment: sip, cámbialo si no te funciona avisa para probar el codigo

Comment: Lo he probado Christian y no funciona. He cogido el código de los objetos y lo he colocado en la parte superior del main, haciendo esto funciona perfectamente... Quizás no se puede acceder a clases remotas.

Comment: si se puede, espera pruebo el codigo

Comment: Christian, ya sé que es... Soy super torpe, la función __init__ tiene dos barras, la mía tiene solo 1 por cada lado. Perdona tío, voy a dar por cerrado este hilo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: justo te iba a decir eso :/, yo no me di cuenta >_<

Comment: Ayer era tarde y estabamos cansados jajajaja esto está al nivel de los ; de Java jajaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema residía en que la función constructor **init** estaba declarada con una _ en cada lado, en vez de sus dobles __. Por ello, el programa no encontraba el constructor de *Triangulo* e intentaba usar un constructor, entiendo que integrado en el sistema, que no necesita datos.